# Difference in hashing algorithms of .Net Identity and .Net Core Identity

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I have two projects with .Net Framework and .Net Core, both use same database.

The database has user details for login and role management and that's done in .Net Identity and .Net Core Identity respectively.

When logging in, both application's `UserManager`s are fetching user with the entered email, but I get incorrect password on one application.

So I want to know whether is there any difference in choice of password hashing algorithm in .Net Identity and .Net Core Identity.

Comment: I'd be surprised, but I guess it's not impossible. What versions of the ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core, and their identity providers, are you using?

Comment: .net 3.0 and core 2.1

Comment: They're probably different. I think ASP.NET Core at least has updated the hashing algorithm to a more modern one.

Comment: If you get chance, I'd upgrade the password hasher to something that uses BCrypt or Argon2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking [this blog post](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/), it would appear that the default algorithms are indeed different

> The default implementation in the Identity framework is the PasswordHasher class (source code). This clas[sic] is designed to work with two different hashing formats:
>
> - ASP.NET Identity Version 2: PBKDF2 with ***HMAC-SHA1***, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, ***1000 iterations***
> - ASP.NET Core Identity Version 3: PBKDF2 with ***HMAC-SHA256***, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, ***10000 iterations***

Emphasis mine

Although they both use PBKDF2 there are some subtle differences

Comment: So my two projects cant work with one login table. right?

Comment: But the code linked there stores the version number of the hash it has used, and looks like it will verify both correctly.

Comment: Looks like you can override which version to use: `services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);`

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#password-hasher-options) explain a little about the ability to work with the two formats.